# Retrieve just the slug in the URL - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to get only the slug (after the domaine name) in wordpress.

Example : [www.helloworld.com/azerty-wxcvbn](http://www.helloworld.com/azerty-wxcvbn)

Need to get with php : 'azerty-wxcvbn'

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the solution

use : `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

for exemple : `https://www.helloworld.com/<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>`